# python utc time minus 5 minutes

Tags: python, time

How to round down a time 5 minutes in Python?

I have this script, but i think this can be easyer, and the full hours the calculation goes wrong. When its 22:03 it returns 21:95 instead of 21:55.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import time

utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
jaar = date.today().year
maand = time.strftime("%m")
dag = time.strftime("%d")
uurutc = utc_datetime.strftime("%H")
autc = utc_datetime.strftime("%M")
minuututc = int(5 * round(float(autc)/5)-5)
uur = time.strftime("%H")
a = time.strftime("%M")
minuut = int(5 * round(float(a)/5)-5)

timestamp = ''.join(str(x) for x in [jaar, maand, dag, uurutc, minuututc])

print timestamp
```

What the code should actually do:

Our local time is UTC+2, but i only need the UTC time, so the output must be in UTC.
Second, the time needs to be 5 min before current time and then round down.
The output format of the string should be: YYYYMMDDHHMM.

Example:

local time: 12:53 > output script: 10:45

local time: 17:07 > output script: 15:00

local time: 08:24 > output script: 06:15

Who can help me with this out?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into `datetime.timedelta`?

Comment: your examples round down to quarter of an hour, not 5 minutes e.g., `10:53` -> `10:45`, not `10:50`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.utcnow()
rounded = now - timedelta(minutes=now.minute % 5 + 5,
                          seconds=now.second,
                          microseconds=now.microsecond)
print rounded
# -> 2014-04-12 00:05:00
```

Comment: Thanks, how to extract 5 minutes of this ?

Comment: Thanks, but i need to extract 5 minutes from that time

Comment: Great that works for me! Last question, how to get the output of this in: YYYYMMDDHHMM ?

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
time = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print(time)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: It also seems to largely overlap with the accepted answer. It’d be useful to call out the differences and explain why you believe the slight variations in syntax are preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `d = d.replace(minute=n*(d.minute // n))` to round down to `n` minutes:

```
>>> d = datetime(2014, 4, 12, 0, 7); print(d.replace(minute=5*(d.minute // 5)))
2014-04-12 00:05:00
>>> n = 15
>>> d = datetime(2014, 4, 12, 10, 53); print(d.replace(minute=n*(d.minute//n)))
2014-04-12 10:45:00
>>> d = datetime(2014, 4, 12, 15, 7); print(d.replace(minute=n*(d.minute//n)))
2014-04-12 15:00:00
>>> d = datetime(2014, 4, 12, 6, 24); print(d.replace(minute=n*(d.minute//n)))
2014-04-12 06:15:00
```

Answer (score -2):

As per the comment above, use the timedelta class:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
five_mins = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

five_mins_ago = now - five_mins

print five_mins_ago
```

Edit: Other answer is better as it covered the rounding