# Standardise Python datetime objects created with read_csv to a 15 minute time for instrumentation data

Tags: python, datetime, csv

I have data from multiple sets of instrumentation with slight variability of timing in csv files.  I want to standardise the time intervals to the nearest modulus 15 minute time period so that I can create a dataframe with data from multiple instruments all aligned to the same time interval.

I do my modulus arithmetic with:-

```
def timeround(dt,multiple):
   import datetime as dt2
   #set the interval required
   #multiple = 15
   a, b = divmod(round(dt.minute, -0), multiple)
   a = a*multiple
   if b >=8  :
     a = a+multiple  
   outputdelta = dt2.timedelta(hours=dt.hour,minutes=a,seconds=00)
   # output a new datetime
return (outputdelta)
```

This works fine with dt entered as

```
dt2 = dt.datetime.now()
```

but with at dtype object returns `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '02-06-2012  18:15:50'`

is there a method to convert that object to a datetime object and can I do this through a call to read_csv

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: [use `d = d.replace(minute=n*(d.minute // n))` to round down to `n` minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27924789/4279)